# Java Framework to validate values (Type identified at RunTime) and Condition (how to compare 2 values) at Run time

Tags: java, spring, comparison

I am currently having a use case to implement in JAVA, and i wanted to seek forum's suggestions if any

**Problem Statement**

We want to do custom comparison between 2 values at runtime

1. the first value is retrieved from DB (would always be String)
2. the second value would be parsed from File (would always be String)

The values though in String, can be Integer, Date, Float, Decimal or String..which is inferred from one of the columns in DB
The condition which needs to be applied between 2 values (for e.g, >=, <=, >, <) is specified in one of the column of DB and available in String format

However, is there a better framework to already take care of same??

Possible Approach:

1. To implement on our own the behavior for comparison based on DataType in java code and Condition in String. But the issue is there are lot of use cases to code and test. Also each time a new condition is added if not covered Code changes are required

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ObjectUtils;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public enum Operation {

    EQUAL_DATE("EQUAL_DATE") {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(Object left, Object right) {
            //Local
            try {
                LocalDate leftDate = (LocalDate) left;
                LocalDate rightDate = (LocalDate) right;
                return leftDate.isEqual(rightDate);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            return true;
        }
    },

    LESS_THAN_EQUAL_DATE("LESSTHANEQUAL_DATE") {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(Object left, Object right) {
            try {
                LocalDate leftDate = (LocalDate) left;
                LocalDate rightDate = (LocalDate) right;
                return leftDate.isBefore(rightDate) || leftDate.isEqual(rightDate);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            return true;
        }
    },

    GREATER_THAN_EQUAL_DATE("GREATERTHANEQUAL_DATE") {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(Object left, Object right) {
            try {
                LocalDate leftDate = (LocalDate) left;
                LocalDate rightDate = (LocalDate) right;
                return leftDate.isEqual(rightDate) || leftDate.isAfter(rightDate);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            return true;
        }
    },
    /**
     * for Data type agnostic checks ANY is appended
     */
    NOT_NULL_ANY("NOT_NULL_ANY") {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(Object left, Object right) {
            // here right doesn't matter, ignore it, always left parameter is the data from file
            return ObjectUtils.allNotNull(left);
        }
    };


    private final String operation;
    private Operation (String operation) {
        this.operation = operation;
    }

    public static Operation parseOperator(String operator) {
        for (Operation op : values()) {
            if (op.operation.equals(operator)) return op;
        }
        throw new NoSuchElementException(String.format("Unknown operator [%s]", operator));
    }
    public abstract boolean apply(Object left, Object right);
}
```

`